# Starting 2 parallel processes in different shell windows

Tags: python, shell, ubuntu, multiprocessing

I got two functions: both for starting Server on particular port. Something like:

```
from Multiprocessing import Process
import sys

def start_server1(port1):
  os.system("server1 --port %s" % port1)
def start_server2(port2):
  os.system("server2 --port %s" % port2)

port1 = arg.sys[1]
port2 = arg.sys[2]
p1 = Process(target=start_server1, args=(port1,))
p2 = Process(target=start_server2, args=(port2,))
```

This allow me to start both servers from `terminal` within my script like

`>>>python servers.py 8000 8001`

But a lot of traces are expected to be displayed for both servers and I want to see them separately. So the question is: how to make so that script will be executed from one `terminal` shell, process `p1` will be started in new shell as well as second process `p2`?

Thank you for advises and suggestions

Comment: change `os.system("server1 --port %s" % port1)` to `os.system("\bin\bash server1 --port %s" % port1)`? Just a guess, I don't have Linux box to test it on.

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect the output of each process in a file.

```
os.system("server1 --port %s > server1.log" % port1)
```

Then, run tail command on each logs in a separate shell to monitor them.

```
tail -f server1.log
```

However, if you are not interested to store the output of those process in a file and want a separate shell solution, you can use "xterm -e" option.

The -e option of xterm allows to run a shell command in a separate xterm window.

```
os.system('xterm -e "server1 --port %s"'% port)
```

Comment: it works not exactly as I expect, but you gave me the proper direction. Thanks!